# Finding the cause of ping spikes on my computer

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a laptop running Windows 8.1 and every minute or two I get a ping spike to something like 300ms. It is not due to the connection because (1) it does never happen on my other laptop (2) the issue arise even with other excellent connections. How can I find the source of these spikes ?

Comment: info missing = 'PC specs, network its on (wireless vs wired), # of computers on your network, Router Type.

Comment: Run network monitor to capture packet, then see what changes inside your network during the ping spike.